# Java 8 M7 - when and where?

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

Does anyone know when and where Java 8's M7 (the developer preview) will land?

I'm looking here:

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/milestones

http://jdk8.java.net/download.html

And I've read:

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8-dev/2013-February/002066.html

But its all about as clear as mud. It's Nashorn I'm after (and I'm lazy, so don't want to do the compile from source dance).

Comment: Really not an SO question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look a the [build 82 changelog](http://download.java.net/jdk8/changes/jdk8-b82.html) it should be in the weekly builds from http://jdk8.java.net/download.html

**Edit**

Nashorn also shows up in the [build 83 changelog](http://download.java.net/jdk8/changes/jdk8-b83.html)